# Creating a fragment using update method of observer pattern declared in main activity in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am not able to figure out how to call the update method declared in the main activity.

MainActivity which has a button when on pressed reads data from a QRscan. After that, a background service is started and data from QRscan is sent to it. It has an update method defined to create a fragment once it is invoked by `notifyobserver`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer{ 
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    NotifyChange Observer = new NotifyChange();
    Observer.addObserver(this);

}
@Override
public void update(Observable observable, Object o) {

    String data = o.toString();
    DialogFragment newFragment = AlertUrlDialog.newInstance(data);
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "processedData");

   }
}
```

The background service processes the data and broadcasts it to the receiver.

DataReceiver.java:

```
public class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   String data = intent.getStringExtra(Service.DATAPROCESSED);

   NotifyChange observer = new NotifyChange();
   observer.dataChange(data);

   }
}
```

now,here is the observable file NotifyChange.Java:

```
public class NotifyChange extends Observable {

public void dataChange(String data) {
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(data);

   }
}
```

Based on analysis using breakpoints, when execution comes to `notifyObservers(data)` , it should call the update method in `MainActivity` but it doesn't. I don't know what is wrong here?

Here is how my app works:

1. MainActivity has a button which when user clicks on it, opens a camera and scans QRCode. MainActivity appears again after the scan.
2. A backgroundsevice is started which broadcasts the result. The Receiver receives the result.
3. Receiver then calls the method in the NotifyChange.java which then calls notifyobserver().

But `notifyobserver()` does not invoke the method update which is defined in mainactivity through which I am creating a fragment to display the result.

Now,another way of creating a fragment after receiving the result from backgroundservice is to start a new activity say `dialogActivity` which then creates the fragment. However,after the creation of the fragment,if the user hits a back button or touches anywhere on the screen except the fragment,then a blank `dialogActivity` is shown instead of `MainActivity`.
Besides, this method feels like a "hacky" way of doing things.

Any ideas would be appreciated. I hope I have communicated my problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figured it out. I am not using the observer pattern but instead I am creating an activity with a style : `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert`. This has helped me solve my problem.

Edit: I found a better way to do it.

If you want to create a dialogbox from broadcastreceiver, then you need to a start an activity which extends FragmentActivity and set its style like `@style/Theme.Appcompt.Dialog.Alert`. In that activity,you can call the fragment to show.

However,if you choose to extend AppCompatActivity instead,it will work but when you try to close your activity, it will show actionbar for split-second which looks weird.